# wkhtmltopdf Exit with code 1 due to network error: HostNotFoundError

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, django-wkhtmltopdf

I'm running `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1.4 (with patched qt)` from a Django application using `django-wkhtmltopdf`.  On my PC it is running fine, but when I load onto a DigitalOcean VPS it is  generating the following error.

> Command '['/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf', '-B', '0', '-L', '0', '-R', '0',
>   '-T', '0', '--allow', 'True', '--enable-local-file-access',
>   '--encoding', 'utf8', '--javascript-delay', '2000',
>   '--page-height', '465mm', '--page-width',
>   '297mm', '--quiet', '/tmp/wkhtmltopdf0xetqkp3.html', '-']' returned
>   non-zero exit status 1.

When I run this from the command line:

```
/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf -B 0 -L 0 -R 0 -T 0 --allow True --enable-local-file-access --encoding utf8 --javascript-delay 2000 --page-height 465mm --page-width 297mm --quiet /tmp/wkhtmltopdf5_sl271s.html -
```

I get the following output:

```
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function sk_num
Error: Failed loading page http:///tmp/wkhtmltopdf5_sl271s.html (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1 due to network error: HostNotFoundError
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
```

It seems to be trying to pick up the file from `http://...` rather than the `tmp` folder so I think I have some settings wrong.

Could anyone help?
Thanks